# What is the best way to share methods between two React components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two React components which I will call R1 and R2.  There is a method that I need which I will call M1 that I need access to from both.

R2 is a sub-component of R1.

The actual method is:

```
  getID(){

    let id = this.props.data.title;

    // replace spaces with _
    id = id.replace(/ /g, '_');

    // this is a special character and if you copy past it into the URL it will be substituted with %FOO
    id = id.replace(/’/g, '_');

    // youtube does not like double underscore in its comments so adjust to use double dash
    // now you can copy paste into youtube.
    id = id.replace(/#/g, '--');

    return id;
  }
```

I could just use the return value.  Is it O.K. to append `id` to `this.props` b.c. props is passed down to R2.

There are many ways to do this obviously but what is best or most robust way.  That is code that is not prone to errors or cause confusion to other developers.

Answer (score 0):

Put them to separate js file and export and then import to the components you need and use.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to call `getID()` from both of the react components, you can pass the function as a property to the child comopnent, like so:

```
<R1 getID={getID}>
    <R2 getID={getID} />
</R1>
```

Then you will be able to call `getID` from `R2` and from `R1`